# Prevent Facebook share web dialog from being opened with Android native app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-share

We have a Facebook share dialog on a webpage to share image that is uploaded by the user. This works fine on desktop (and iOS). However Android devices allow you to open the share dialog(which is a browser popup on mobile devices) using the native Facebook app.

[image]

However the native app doesn't receive the data/info passed to the `FB.ui` method, as such it uses the data taken from the Open Graph attributes on the page to share. And because of that it's not the uploaded image that gets shared, but the default one from `og:image`.

**Native app(default page image)**

[image]

**Browser popup(the uploaded image)**

[image]

How could we solve this issue. Is there any way to pass the info to the app? Or could we prevent Android from giving the user the choice to use the native app?

Comment: FYI: Incentivizing users to share content onto their Facebook profiles to take part in some kind of competition/raffle is a clear violation of FB policies.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all comes to your page having wrong markup. Passing markup via Facebook API is unreliable and the page will have the wrong meta data if the user manually shares the page (via copy pasting the link) on Facebook or other social sites that use the Open Graph markup.

If it's technically possible, I would look into incorporating the right markup, including the og:image on the page which would solve this problem instead of working around it.